# $cordovaInAppBrowser.open works with _blank on iOs and _self on Android

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have built an ionic app.
On android, I have been using the following code:

```
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open(url, '_self', options)
            .then(function (event) {
                // success
                console.log('success --> ' + event);
            })
            .catch(function (event) {
                // error
                console.log('error --> ' + event);

            });
```

Further on I have:

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstart', function (e, event) { ..}
```

I found that for Android, the above loadStart event is fired, however on iOS I had to change the '_self' string to '_blank' for it to work (i.e. the loadstart event then fires).

Any reason why this is happening?

I now have to detect if I am on an iOS device and pass the correct string (_blank or _self).